# How to highlight cell "X" rows under "Search TEXT"

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I am looking for a way to apply conditional formatting to a column in Excel such that each time a certain text string is found it highlights the cell exactly 60 rows below it.

For example if Rows 1 & 20 have the text "Buy" then rows 61 & 80 should be highlighted in Green.

It needs to count cells even if they are blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer so posting it in case others have the same problem.

I have used a INDIRECT formula as follows:

=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+X,COLUMN()+Y))=Z   -   Row()+X & Column+Y can be used to offset so in my case I want to check the cell 60 rows above so will use ROW()-60,COLUMN()

So I will use the following formula for my conditional format

=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-60,COLUMN()))="Buy"